# having error in setting textview from json parsing

Tags: java, android

I want to set `textview` in my XML which I have parsed from Json but I am unable to do so can anybody help me with

```
private TextView tv_traveller_name;
private String name;
tv_traveller_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_traveller_name);


JSONObject(dataObject.getString("name"));
name = nameObject.getString("name");
Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: name : " + name);
tv_traveller_name.setText(name);
```

JSON response

> "statusCode":"ok","data":[{"name":"khclycl","mobileNo":2580258025,"email":"khckhckhc","bookingCode":"ZB200228170330","price":{"totalPrice":1200,"basePrice":1142.86,"gst":57.14,"couponValue":0,"totalPayablePrice":1200},"status":"CREATED","createdOn":1582889610007,"boardingPoint":{"name":"Majnu
>   Ka Tila, Delhi","time":1582894800000,"address":"Near Nirmal Hirday
>   Church","lat":28.703972,"lng":77.227194,"city":"Delhi"},"dropPoint":{"name":"Patlikuhal
>   Bypass near fishfarm, Manali","time":1582941600000,"address":"Private
>   Bus Parking
>   Manali","lat":32.119611,"lng":77.147694,"city":"Manali"},"departureDate":1582894800000,"tripChart":[{"id":"5e58fa8a9f0bfe093278b8df","name":"khclycl","gender":"M","status":"CREATED","tripChartCode":"TZB2002281703300","seatLabel":"18"}],"couponApplied":"","transactionType":"PG","id":"5e58fa8a9f0bfe093278b8dd","busType":{"_id":"5d7633d14947d40f2be0269d","name":"Volvo
>   Single
>   Axle","isAc":true,"seatArrangementTypeId":"5d7632044947d40f2be02649","createdOn":1568027601982,"lastModifiedOn":1568027601982},"canCancel":true,"isVirtualTrip":false}]}
>   2020-02-28 17:03:37.087 15270-15270/com.example.zingbus
>   E/com.example.zingbus.Activity.BookingComfirmedActivity: exception:
>   Value
>   [{"name":"khclycl","mobileNo":2580258025,"email":"khckhckhc","bookingCode":"ZB200228170330","price":{"totalPrice":1200,"basePrice":1142.86,"gst":57.14,"couponValue":0,"totalPayablePrice":1200},"status":"CREATED","createdOn":1582889610007,"boardingPoint":{"name":"Majnu
>   Ka Tila, Delhi","time":1582894800000,"address":"Near Nirmal Hirday
>   Church","lat":28.703972,"lng":77.227194,"city":"Delhi"},"dropPoint":{"name":"Patlikuhal
>   Bypass near fishfarm, Manali","time":1582941600000,"address":"Private
>   Bus Parking
>   Manali","lat":32.119611,"lng":77.147694,"city":"Manali"},"departureDate":1582894800000,"tripChart":[{"id":"5e58fa8a9f0bfe093278b8df","name":"khclycl","gender":"M","status":"CREATED","tripChartCode":"TZB2002281703300","seatLabel":"18"}],"couponApplied":"","transactionType":"PG","id":"5e58fa8a9f0bfe093278b8dd","busType":{"_id":"5d7633d14947d40f2be0269d","name":"Volvo
>   Single
>   Axle","isAc":true,"seatArrangementTypeId":"5d7632044947d40f2be02649",

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".Activity.BookingComfirmedActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/extra_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/tv_traveller_name"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/extra_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"

                android:id="@+id/tv_pnr"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/extra_light"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
         </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/line_hor"/>

            </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:weightSum="7"
              android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/iconarrow"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:textSize="18sp"

                android:textColor="@color/homeColor" />

    </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curve_round_box"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/tv_bus_type"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/tv_seat"
                android:textColor="@color/MyPink"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_start_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:textColor="@color/homeColor"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_start_place"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:src="@drawable/line"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time_difference"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"

                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/line"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_end_time"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/homeColor"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_trip_end_place"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/prosoft"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_marginStart="10dp">
             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_base_fare"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>

             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_gst"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>

             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_total_fare"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_discount"
                     android:textColor="@color/Green"/>

             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="25dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_coupon"
                     android:textColor="@color/MyPink"/>

             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 >

                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/line_hor"/>


             </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:weightSum="2">
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:textSize="20sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:textSize="20sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                     android:id="@+id/tv_amount_paid"
                     android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

             </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: its not showing in xml the field comes out blank

Comment: The value is logged ?
If yes, post your xml here also

Comment: what is error in the logCat?

Comment: added above can check

Comment: data from the parsing come no log there

Comment: Please paste full xml layout top to bottom.

Comment: Paste the json response also.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code snippet and let me know whether its working or not?

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            String status = jsonObject.getString("statusCode");
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                    String name = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    tv_traveller_name.setText(name);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```